# apache beam 2.2 pipeline.apply no such method exception

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());
            DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
            options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
            options.setStagingLocation("gs://bucketname/stageapache");
            options.setTempLocation("gs://bucketname/stageapachetemp");
            options.setProject("projectid");
            Pipeline p=Pipeline.create(options);
    p.apply(TextIO.read().from("gs://bucketname/filename.csv"));
//p.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern("gs://bucketname/f.csv"));
            p.run();
        }
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Error

```
Dec 08, 2017 5:09:35 PM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner fromOptions
INFO: PipelineOptions.filesToStage was not specified. Defaulting to files from the classpath: will stage 85 files. Enable logging at DEBUG level to see which files will be staged.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.createPrimitiveOutputInternal(Lorg/apache/beam/sdk/Pipeline;Lorg/apache/beam/sdk/values/WindowingStrategy;Lorg/apache/beam/sdk/values/PCollection$IsBounded;)Lorg/apache/beam/sdk/values/PCollection;
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.PrimitiveParDoSingleFactory$ParDoSingle.expand(PrimitiveParDoSingleFactory.java:68)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.PrimitiveParDoSingleFactory$ParDoSingle.expand(PrimitiveParDoSingleFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyReplacement(Pipeline.java:550)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.replace(Pipeline.java:280)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.replaceAll(Pipeline.java:201)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.replaceTransforms(DataflowRunner.java:688)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:498)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:153)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:303)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:289)
    at com.pearson.apachebeam.StarterPipeline.main(StarterPipeline.java:60)
```

In the above code if add FileIO/TextIO line i am getting the above error, with out adding that line if i run it is creating job since there is no operations in it is failing. i am stuck up at this in my development i migrated to apache beam 2.2 to get control of the file we read  from storage

Help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `pom.xml` is depending on different components of the Beam SDK at different versions: `beam-sdks-java-core` at 2.2.0, but `beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform` and `beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java` at 2.0.0. They need to be at the same version.